# Any way to manually make a variable more important in a machine learning model?

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, feature-selection

Sometimes you know by experience or by some expert knowledge some variable will play a key role in this model, is there a way to manually make the variable count more so the training process can speed up and the method can combine some human knowledge/wisdom/intelligence.

I still think machine learning combined with human knowledge is the strongest weapon we have now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work **by scaling your input data accordingly**.

> On the other hand the strength of a neural network is to figure out
>   which features are in fact important and which combinations with other
>   features are important - from the data.

You might argue, that you'll decrease training time. Somebody else might argue that you're biasing your training in such a way that it might even take more time.

Anyway if you would want to do this, assuming a fully connected layer, you could **increasedly initialize the weights of the input feature** you found important.

Another way, could be to first **pretrain the model** according to a training loss, that should have your feature as an output. Than keep the weights and switch to the actual loss - I have never tried this, but it could work.

Comment: First thank you very much,And I didn't quite get the last step of your suggestion, "pre-train the model with feature as output then keep the weights and switch to the actual loss", can you explain it?

Comment: E.g. you want to classify circles from rectangles - you figure out that the shape feature might be important and want to magnify the influence of the shape feature. Thus you pretrain your model to return the shape as an output. Only then are you keeping the weights and training your model to do the actual task.

Comment: kind of understand, thank you very much